# Adding Header to existing PDF File using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to add a Header to an existing PDF file. It works but the table header in the existing PDF are messed up by the change in the font. If I remove setting the font then the header doesn't show up. Here is my code:

```
    // the document
    PDDocument doc = null;
    try
    {
        doc = PDDocument.load( file );

        List allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        //PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

        for( int i=0; i<allPages.size(); i++ )
        {
            PDPage page = (PDPage)allPages.get( i );
            PDRectangle pageSize = page.findMediaBox();
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true,true);
            PDFont font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
            float fontSize = 15.0f;
            contentStream.beginText();
            // set font and font size
            contentStream.setFont( font, fontSize);
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(700, 1150);
            contentStream.drawString( message);
            contentStream.endText();

            //contentStream.
            contentStream.close();}

        doc.save( outfile );
    }
    finally
    {
        if( doc != null )
        {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: *the table header in the existing PDF are messed up* - how exactly are they messed up?

Comment: The font used has made the table header un readable. For e.g. the table header used to be PMITS Asset ID and after adding the header it reads as: 3 0 , 7 6  $ V V H W. some gibrish characters.

Comment: So your source PDF or PDFBox is buggy. Unfortunately I have already recognized an issue in the PDFBox code which might cause your problem: A page does not necessarily have its own resources pool but can inherit it from an ancestor in the page tree. `PDPageContentStream` on the other hand ignores such inherited resources and in such a situation creates a new, empty resource pool for the page. Thus, in such a case inherited font information are lost. This might result in your gibrish. Please provide the PDF in question to verify whether this PDFBox bug is indeed the issue you observe.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Is it possible for you to send me your email address? I don't want to publish my PDF here. Please send an email to: anita_avadhani@yahoo.com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially you are running into a PDFBox bug in the current version 1.8.2.

## A workaround:

Add a `getFonts` call of the page resources after creating the new content stream before using a font:

```
PDPage page = (PDPage)allPages.get( i );
PDRectangle pageSize = page.findMediaBox();
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true,true);
page.getResources().getFonts();  // <<<<<<<<
PDFont font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
float fontSize = 15.0f;
contentStream.beginText();
```

## The bug itself:

The bug is in the method `PDResources.addFont` which is called from `PDPageContentStream.setFont`:

```
public String addFont(PDFont font) 
{
    return addFont(font, MapUtil.getNextUniqueKey( fonts, "F" ));
}
```

It uses the current content of the `fonts` member variable to determine a unique name for the new font resource on the page at hand. Unfortunately this member variable still *can be* (and in your case *is*) uninitialized at this time. This results in the `MapUtil.getNextUniqueKey( fonts, "F" )` call to always return **F0**.

The `font` variable then is initialized implicitly during the `addFont(PDFont, String)` call later.

Thus, if unfortunately there already existed a font named **F0** on that page, it is replaced by the new font.

Having tested with your PDF this is exactly what happens in your case. As the existing font **F0** uses some custom encoding while your replacement font uses a standard one, the text originally written using **F0** now looks like gibberish.

The work-around mentioned above implicitly initializes that member variable and, thus, prevents the font replacement.

If you plan to use PDFBox in production for this task, you might want to report the bug.

PS: As mentioned in the comments above there is another bug to observe in context with inherited resources. It should be brought to the PDFBox development's attention, too.

PPS: The issue at hand meanwhile has been fixed in PDFBox for versions 1.8.3 and 2.0.0, cf. [PDFBOX-1753](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1753).

Comment: Thank you so much mkl, this works like a champ. Thanks again for taking the time to look into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
        try(PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();) {
        /* Initialize and create a landscape page */
        PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(595, 842));
        page.setMediaBox(new PDRectangle(PDRectangle.A4.getHeight(),
                PDRectangle.A4.getWidth()));

        /* Add page to PDDocument */
        doc.addPage(page);

        PDFont font = PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD;
        float mainHeadingfontSize = 20;
        float subHeadingfontSize = 10;

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        contentStream.setFont(font, mainHeadingfontSize);

        float pageWidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();
        float textWidth = font.getStringWidth("View FI Data") / 1000 * mainHeadingfontSize;
        float centerCoordinate = (pageWidth - textWidth) /2;
        float upperRightYCordinate = page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY() - 50;

        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(centerCoordinate, upperRightYCordinate);
        contentStream.setFont(font, mainHeadingfontSize);
        contentStream.showText("View FI Data");
        contentStream.endText();

        contentStream.setFont(font,subHeadingfontSize);
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(centerCoordinate - 300, upperRightYCordinate - 60);
        contentStream.showText("Profile");
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();

        doc.save(response.getOutputStream());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("unable to generate pdf using Fi Data Tables : {}",e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Your code creates a new page while the use case of the question is editing an existing page. So how does your answer relate to the question?

Comment: it is useful for those who are creating pdf using pdf BOx. ofcourse anyone can read pdf and use the same code to add headings and sbheadings