# PDFBox scrambling the text

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have been trying to edit a PDF document to pre-fill form entries. I've got it working (sort of). The text I'm adding, goes in fine. However, other text that was already there seems to have gotten replaced with "&%£!£! symbols. I've worked out that it's something to do with the "contentStream" section in the code below. It seems to be the "setFont" line. If I remove it, the page remains OK... except that the "Hello Richard" text is no longer displayed!

Help please!

```
package pdfboxtest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;

public class PDFFormFiller {

    private static final String R40_NEW_FORM_PATH = "c:\\temp\\hmrc-r40.pdf";
    private static final String R40_COMPLETED_FORM_PATH = "c:\\temp\\hmrc-r40-complete.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(R40_NEW_FORM_PATH);

        addTextToPage(doc);

        doc.save(R40_COMPLETED_FORM_PATH);
        doc.close();
    }

    private static void addTextToPage(PDDocument doc) throws Exception {
        List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        PDPage firstPage = (PDPage) pages.get(0);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, firstPage, true, true);

        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 24);
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 200);
        contentStream.drawString("HELLO RICHARD!!");
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();

    }
}
```

[image: This is the top of the form before I add text elsewhere]
[image: And after I've added text elsewhere, this bit of text goes nuts! I did not edit this bit though]

Comment: Longshot but have you tried loading a font from the system like so? PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF (document, "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\segoepr.ttf");

Comment: That was definitely worth a stab! Thank you, but no luck :-(

Comment: This could be due to a PDFBox issue I described a workaround for in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322553/adding-header-to-existing-pdf-file-using-pdfbox/19512650#19512650).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already assumed in a comment, this is *due to a PDFBox issue I described a workaround for in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322553/adding-header-to-existing-pdf-file-using-pdfbox/19512650#19512650).* This issue is still present in the version 1.8.2 of PDFBox but meanwhile has been fixed for versions 1.8.3 and 2.0.0, cf. [PDFBOX-1753](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1753).

In your case the workaround changes the `addTextToPage` method like this:

```
private static void addTextToPage(PDDocument doc) throws IOException {
    List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    PDPage firstPage = (PDPage) pages.get(0);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, firstPage, true, true);

    firstPage.getResources().getFonts(); // <<<<<<

    contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 24);
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 200);
    contentStream.drawString("HELLO RICHARD!!");
    contentStream.endText();
    contentStream.close();
}
```

The added line enforces an initialization which `new PDPageContentStream` forgets but `setFont` counts on having been done. You can find details in the answer referenced above. You might want to inform PDFBox development.

Comment: Superb! Thank you. I can assure you I did do some searching around on StackOverflow, but I probably didn't evaluate that answer you gave me properly. Wow, what a fiddly little issue!