# Encoding Problems after using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, pdfbox

I have to

1. extract text from a pdf, where i roughly use this

   ```
   f = IOUtility.getFileForPath(filePath);
   RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
   PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(randomAccessFile);
   parser.parse();
   cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
   pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
   pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
   pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
   pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());
   String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
   ```
2. scale the PDF

   ```
   File PDFFile = IOUtility.getFileForPath(scaleConfig.getFilePath());
   document = PDDocument.load(PDFFile);

   for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
       PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
       float tx = ((cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + cropBox.getUpperRightX()) * 0.03f) / 2;
       float ty = ((cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + cropBox.getUpperRightY()) * 0.03f) / 2;
       PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false, false);
       cs.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(0.97f, 0.97f));
       cs.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty));
       cs.close();
   }
   document.save(scaleConfig.getTargetFilePath());
   ```
3. and finally write something on every page of the pdf. I use one of the 14 supported Fonts mentioned here https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/workingwithfonts.html. Times New Roman in this case.

   ```
   File PDFFile = IOUtility.getFileForPath(writeConfig.getFilePath());
   document = PDDocument.load(PDFFile);
   for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
       PDFBoxHelper.fixRotation(document, page);
       writeStringOnPage(document, page, writeConfig);
   }
   document.save(writeConfig.getTargetFilePath());
   ```

   with `writeStringOnPage` doing

   ```
   contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false, true);
   WriteCoordinates writeCoordinates = WriteCoordinateFactory.buildCoordinates(writeConfig, page.getMediaBox());
   contentStream.beginText();
   // lower left x and lower left y are different after rotation so use those for your calculation
   contentStream.newLineAtOffset(writeCoordinates.getX(), writeCoordinates.getY());
   contentStream.setFont(writeConfig.getFont(), writeConfig.getFontSize());
   contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(writeConfig.getFontColor());
   contentStream.showText(writeConfig.getToWrite());
   contentStream.endText();
   ```

I left out signatures and catch blocks because of company reasons. I always close the contentstreams.

Most of the time the processed PDFs look fine both in Chrome PDF-Viewer, Acrobat Reader and also after importing them into BMD.
But in some specific cases i seem to have encoding issues and certain parts are not displayed correctly.
All the text I add on the PDF is correctly displayed all of the time.

I realized only boldly printed text in the PDF is displayed wrong so I used Adobe Acrobat Reader to look at the fonts used.

[image: eingebettete Schriften]

Arial and Arial,Bold are Embedded and encoded with Identity-H. As Everything written bold I concluded that all text written in Arial,Bold is displayed wrong. Everything else is still fine after processing the pdf. I can not add the pdf because it has customer data but here are some examples:

1. **Rechnungs-Nr: --> 5HFKQXQJV1U**
2. **60 Tage netto (27.12.2019) -> 7DJHQHWWR**

If the PDF is imported in BMD without PDFBox-manipulation it is displayed correctly.

I tried to narrow the problem down by only scaling and only writing but the problem occurred both times.

I am using PDFBox 2.017 and Java 8.

As the error also occurs when i am only scaling the pdf I used **PDFDebugger** to compare the original PDF:

[image: orignal PDF]

and the pdf after i scaled it:

[image: scaled PDF]

The only thing that seems different/off is the Contents Entry.

When I open the scaled PDF an click on the Fonts section and on the Arial,Bold font i get a lot of warnings about unicode mappings. The PDF is correctly displayed in PDFDebugger though.

[image: warnings]

I am neither an expert with PDFBox nor with fonts and encodings so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That reminds me of [an old pdfbox issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705887/1729265). But that issue had been fixed s long time ago. You may want to try the work-around anyways.

Comment: If that's not solving your issue, though, we'll likely need example files before and after manipulation that allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: Try reproducing the effect with a non confidential file. Try also using a different font, i.e. try creating your font with PDType0Font.load() just to see what happens.

Comment: Another thing to try if you can't provide any file: have a look at the font resources of a file where it worked and a file where it didn't work with PDFDebugger.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you for the input! I updated my question with your suggestion to look at the file with PDFDebugger as the problem already occurs when I only scale the PDF - so I thought it is less likely to be a problem with how I add text. Maybe you know what to make of the PDFDebugger output?

Comment: What happens if you just open and save the PDF without scaling, i.e. just open and save the PDF - is the result PDF ok or not? When you open the source and result PDFs in PDFDebugger from the command line, are there any errors / warnings? Can PDFDebugger display the "bad" result PDF properly or not? If the problem happens with scaling, what is in the prepended content stream? [9 0 R]

Comment: This PDFDebugger version https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ will put any errors / warnings into a separate window (click on the status line on the bottom right if there is a text there)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr the content stream [9 0 R] contains only:
0.97 0 0 0.97 0 0 cm
1 0 0 1 8.925 12.62835 cm
To check if the PDF is correctly displayed in BMD when only opening and saving I sadly will have to wait for either Access Credentials to BMD or an answer from the department (they reported the error)
I used the mentioned PDFDebugger Version on the scaled pdf and as soon as i clicked on the Font section I got a lot of warnings. All of them are about not having an unicode mapping for the Arial,Bold font. I updated my question with a screenshot of some lines of the error.

Comment: These font warnings are harmless, I was wondering whether any warnings / errors come up when opening the file when the page is displayed. And what is "BMD"? And is the page in the previously mentioned "bad" PDF displayed properly in all tools or only in BMD?

Comment: BMD is Accounting Software and the invoices can also be displayed in it. 
The weird thing is that the PDF can be displayed correctly in BMD. But after touching it with PDFBox it is not correctly displayed anymore.
In Chrome PDF-Viewer or Adobe Acrobat it is correctly displayed before and after editing.

Comment: Weird. I wonder what display tool BMD uses - and can you create a ticket with them? They can contact us if they think it's our fault. Another idea: add this to your code before saving: `document.getDocument().setIsXRefStream(false);`

Comment: I now have access to BMD directly and was able to test a lot.
1) If I only open and save the PDF - the problem does occur.
2) Nevertheless i tried @mkl suggestion to test out the old pdfbox issue which sadly did not work. 
3) I also tried document.getDocument().setIsXRefStream(false) which also did not resolve this issue.

As I know have excess to BMD i looked at the PDFViewer and found an About-Box. BMD seems to use WPViewPDF 4.1.8.2 Plus. I then found a site where one can download the demo version : http://www.wpcubed.com/pdf/download/wpviewpdf-and-wpviewpdf-plus-demo-component/

Comment: In the above mentioned demo-version the error does occur too so I highly suspect that the viewer itself has a problem. The only thing I do not understand is why he can display it before touching this file with pdfbox. Also the error only occurs with this file - so far.

Comment: Can you access the PDF written by PDFBox but before it is uploaded to BMD and store it elsewhere? And after upload to BMD download it again from there? And then compare those two files? (Without you sharing the files in question, this is all pure guesswork here...)

Comment: I can and did but I do not really see what could cause this issue. Would you be willing to look at the file before and after? I can send the exact file with the issue (before and after) by email (company allows it).

Comment: @leherv You can find an email address in my stack overflow profile.

Comment: @mkl Thank you very much - I just sent them to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In short

The relevant difference is that PDFBox serializes names differently. But the different outputs according to the PDF specification are equivalent, so you apparently have uncovered a WPViewPDF bug.

#### The difference in writing names

In the original PDF (raw.pdf) you find the names **NOWFJV+Arial,Bold** and **NOWFJV+Arial,Bold-WinCharSetFFFF**, in all files manipulated by PDFBox you find all occurrences of those names outside of content streams replaced by **NOWFJV+Arial#2CBold** and **NOWFJV+Arial#2CBold-WinCharSetFFFF**.

WPViewPDF cannot properly display the text written in the fonts with these changed names. After patching the PDFs back to contain a comma in place of the '#2C' in those names, WPViewPDF again properly displays such text.

I would assume WPViewPDF finds **NOWFJV+Arial,Bold** in the content stream and expects to find the matching font definition in the page resources using the identically written name, so it doesn't recognize it with the name **NOWFJV+Arial#2CBold**.

#### Is that a PDFBox bug?

According to the PDF specification,

> Any character in a name that is a regular character (other than NUMBER SIGN) shall be written as itself or by using its 2-digit hexadecimal code, preceded by the NUMBER SIGN.

*(ISO 32000-2, section 7.3.5 "Name objects")*

Thus, this replacement of commas in names by '#2C' sequences is a completely valid alternative way to write those names.

Thus, no, it's not a PDFBox bug but apparently a WPViewPDF bug.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will report the problem and let us hope they will fix it!