# PDFbox 1.7.0 - How to keep existing image while adding new one with PDFBox?

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox 1.7.0 (I do not have a choice for the version due to old version in production server). I am trying to add an image to an existing PDF which has already a logo.
When I add the new image, the old one disappears like it is replaced.

```java
// Use for convert mm to dots
// ... 72 dots per inch
static final int DEFAULT_USER_SPACE_UNIT_DPI = 72;
// ... mm -> inch -> dots
static final float MM_TO_UNITS = 1 / (10 * 2.54f) * DEFAULT_USER_SPACE_UNIT_DPI;

/**
 * Add a given image to a specific page of a PDF
 * @param document PDF document to manipulate
 * @param input image inputStream
 * @param pdfpage page number to target
 * @param x image position (en mm)
 * @param y image position (en mm)
 * @param width max width of the image (mm)
 * @param height max height of the image (en mm)
 * @param opacity opacity level of the image (fraction)
 */
void addImageToPage (PDDocument document, InputStream input, int pdfpage, int x, int y, int width, int height, float opacity) throws IOException {
    if (input != null) {
        // Convert inputstream to usable BufferedImage
        BufferedImage tmp_image = ImageIO.read (input);
        // User TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR to fix PDFBox issue with transparent PNG
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage (tmp_image.getWidth(), tmp_image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        // Prepare the image
        image.createGraphics().drawRenderedImage (tmp_image, null);
        PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDPixelMap (document, image);
        // Resize the image
        int iWidth = ximage.getWidth();
        int iHeight = ximage.getHeight();
        if (width / height > iWidth / iHeight) {
            ximage.setWidth (Math.round (width * MM_TO_UNITS));
            ximage.setHeight (Math.round ((iHeight * width / iWidth) * MM_TO_UNITS));
        } else {
            ximage.setWidth (Math.round ((iWidth * height / iHeight) * MM_TO_UNITS));
            ximage.setHeight (Math.round (height * MM_TO_UNITS));
        }
        // Retrieve the page to update
        PDPage page = (PDPage)document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get (pdfpage);
        PDResources resources = page.findResources();
        // Get graphics states
        Map graphicsStates = resources.getGraphicsStates();
        if (graphicsStates == null) {
            graphicsStates = new HashMap();
        }
        // Set graphics states configurations
        PDExtendedGraphicsState extendedGraphicsState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
        // Set the opacity of the image
        extendedGraphicsState.setNonStrokingAlphaConstant (opacity);
        graphicsStates.put ("TransparentState", extendedGraphicsState);
        // Restore graphics states
        resources.setGraphicsStates (graphicsStates);
        // Retrieve the content stream
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream (document, page, true, true);
        // Activate transparency options
        contentStream.appendRawCommands ("/TransparentState gs\n");
        contentStream.endMarkedContentSequence();
        // Insert image
        contentStream.drawImage (
            ximage,
            (float) x * MM_TO_UNITS,
            (float) y * MM_TO_UNITS
        );
        // close the stream
        contentStream.close();
    }
}
```

I expected to have the new image within the page, but the existing image inside the page has disappeared instead of the new one.

Example of used PDF : http://www.mediafire.com/folder/g6p7c2b5ob1c7/PDFBox_issue

Comment: Try setting the fifth constructor of `PDPageContentStream` to `true`. (If it exists in 1.7)

Comment: I have the fifth parameter (named resetContext) but it changes nothing whatever the setted value.

Comment: Then upload old and new PDF so that we can have a look.

Comment: I have uploaded an example of the PDF used for testing. 
"old.pdf" is the original and "new.pdf" is the obtained PDF after modification.

Comment: OK, the fifth parameter isn't relevant for this file. What really happens is that for some reason, the existing image resource entry gets lost. Can you try to remove all code that accesses the resources dictionary? The "TransparentState" thing isn't needed anyway for this test since opacity is 1.

Comment: There already is something fishy with the original file old.pdf. RUPS at least seems to have issues opening it.

Comment: Ok. I tried to create another old.pdf from Office Writer with a single image inside it and nothing else. Then I have cleaned the code by removing the different accesses to the resources and the TransparenceState instruction also. No improvment :(
Maybe it is a pecular bug from the 1.7 version of PDFBox...

Comment: I found a bug in 1.7, but I don't know if this affects you. To work around it, do this before creating your page content stream: `page.setResources(page.findResources());`. (I can't look at your PDFs right now from here, sorry, although I did yesterday). The interesting question would be whether `page.getResources()` returns null without the workaround and before creating the page content stream.

Comment: @Tilman this sounds somewhat related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19512650/1729265)

Comment: Indeed, the end mentions it; and the beginning fits the answer too, almost… coincidentally, one of the things I tried was to call `page.getResources().getXObjects()` but that didn't work for that version… the problem is that it is different `resources` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have given up trying to use PDFbox 1.7 for this part of the development. It requirement to many fixes to implements few things. It is not really maintainable for the future works. Thanks to everyone for the hints and helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are several bugs in 1.7... one I mentioned in a comment (turns out it doesn't affect you), the other one is that the resources does some caching but isn't managed properly… long story short, you need to save and restore your xobject resources like this:

```
Map<String, PDXObject> xObjectsMap = page.getResources().getXObjects(); // save xobjects
…
PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDPixelMap (document, image);
String imgName = page.getResources().addXObject(ximage, "Im");
cs.drawImage(ximage, 0, 0); // bug happens here, old xobjects gets lost
xObjectsMap.put(imgName, ximage);
page.getResources().setXObjects(xObjectsMap); // restore xobjects
```

This is really just a workaround… there may be more bad surprises coming. You should not use old versions. They no longer spark joy. You should thank them for their service and then let them go without guilt.